# bucket not exists with localstack and s3

Tags: go, amazon-s3, localstack

`Im trying run localstack via docker-compose to create S3 with Golang
im using docker-compose:

and connect S3:

and create bucket with : aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3api create-bucket --bucket tags
but, im received error "Bucket not exists" all time!
help pls
`

Comment: docker-compose: 
version: '3.0'

services:

localstack:
image: localstack/localstack:latest
environment: 
 - AWS_REGION=localhost
 - EDGE_PORT=4566
 - SERVICES=dynamodb,s3
 - KINESIS_PROVIDER=kinesalite
 - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=local
 - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=local
 - AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=TOKEN
 - DEBUG=1
 - DATA_DIR=./data
ports:
 - '4566:4566'
 - "4572:4572" # s3
volumes:
 - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

Comment: and connect S3:

func (c *Container) connectS3() *s3.S3 {
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
 Region:   aws.String(c.Config().DynamoDBConfig.AwsRegion),
 Endpoint: aws.String(c.Config().DynamoDBConfig.Endpoint),
})
if err != nil {
 log.Fatal(err)
}
svc := s3.New(sess)
return svc
}

Comment: and create bucket with : aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3api create-bucket --bucket tags
but, im received error "Bucket not exists" all time!
help pls

Answer (score 0):

Hi – Please update your Docker Compose configuration to accurately reflect the latest updates:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
    environment:
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG-}
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR-}
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

You can now create an S3 bucket using the AWS CLI:

```bash
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3api create-bucket --bucket tags
```

If you run into troubles, please check if LocalStack is running properly:

```bash
curl localhost:4566/_localstack/health
```